# Reading a Matlab file of numbers and printing them out

Tags: matlab, file, io

I have a file named signal.txt like so:

```
5.2530
5.2531
5.2534
5.2539
5.2544
5.2550
```

and I am trying to open the file and save the contents into a variable so that I may later use
them for future use. What I have so far is this:

```
clc
clear
close all

% This project will require you to implement the DFT computation for a 
% given signal in a MATLAB script and compare your output to the output of 
% the MATLAB fft() function.

formatSpec = '%1.4f\n';
fp = fopen('signal.txt','r');
numberArray = fscanf(fp,formatSpec);
fprintf('The number are: %f',numberArray)
fclose(fp);
```

Thank you and any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? Just how to read the file and print it out? Or did you have some questions about your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write your own code to read the file. [`readmatrix()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readmatrix.html), or in older versions [`dlmread()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) will do the job for you.

```
numberArray = readmatrix('signal.txt');
% or,
numberArray = dlmread('signal.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

the only thing wrong was `formatSpec` needs to equal `'%f'` instead of what I had previously:

```
formatSpec = '%f';
```